# Checking my code in Virtual Machine (VirtualBox)

Tags: php, symfony, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm totally new to servers and VirtualBox. Tried to search, but couldn't find what I need (maybe didn't know what to search).

So I'll try to explain what I want.
I want to code like I used to on Windows with my PHP IDE and to test the code instantly - best is to be able to test it on some VM. Lets say I change some code and after browser refresh I want to see changes.

I want to have some server on VirtualBox as much alike as I plan to deploy my Symfony2 project to. Admin of the server said he has HDD dd image (some nix `dd` command). I found out, that I'll have to convert this image to VDI or VMDK format using some `VBoxManage` (still don't know nothing about it).

I'm using Win 8.1 Pro. Did download VirtualBox installer, but didn't install it yet, because after reading documentation, I was confused if it's even possible to achieve what I want.

Is it?
If it is, maybe I could get step by step instructions what to install and how to configure all software?
If it's not, maybe there's some way to get close to what I want?

Comment: Why don't you get WAMP and run a server locally?

Comment: I want the dev environment to be as much the same to production as possible.

Comment: I don't use windows, but I have VM Ware on my mac at home to run Ubuntu and I'm not so sure there's an easy way to copy files between the main machine and virtual machine without going through somewhere else first, like a Git repo. On my local machine at work I just have it set up to automatically add->commit->push to our dev server so I see my changes; that might be an option for you.

Comment: @jraede You definitely can map file system paths to VMs.  You can either use what's built into VirtualBox, or something like SSH, Samba, or NFS.

Comment: So, so like SSHFS from virtual to main, or vice versa? Interesting, never thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

I use a method similar to what you are talking about for developing PHP code across multiple frameworks/platforms.

I would recommend looking at [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) for managing the development VM as well as [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) for helping to provision the VM itself.  That said, there are many many many repos out there that have a setup for a given PHP framework, and all you have to do is 'clone' and 'vagrant up' to have a fully provisioned and deployd virtual machine that points to a folder in the cloned repo for all of its application source code.

It's coding nirvana in my opinion.  I modify the file locally using whatever IDE I like...the folder is mounted in the VM so my changes are live as soon as I save the file.

You mentioned symphony2, so here is a link to a vagrant setup for [symphony2](https://github.com/irmantas/symfony2-vagrant).

While you can clone and vagrant up without knowing the internals, I still recommend learning about Vagrant and Puppet.  You can always build your own custom Vagrantfile and puppet setup to get the exact environment you want to replicate, or add/remove things from a cloned image to make it fit what you want.

Good luck!

Comment: In stead of Puppet, you might want to check out [Ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com). It doesn't need a client/guest daemon (but issues commands through SSH) and it's very easy to use/learn.

Comment: Agreed!  Ansible is next on my learning list, having done Puppet and Chef.  I would love to talk about the client/guest daemon...i sounds like you are referring to something similar to Chef's server...and while you can run puppet in a networked setup with clients and servers, you definitely don't have to!  I run puppet in standalone (similar to chef solo) mode as a general rule.

Comment: Actually Ansible only has a "server" but no "clients", not in the sense of installing/running anything on them. The client machines only need a SSH server, which 99.9% of them have anyway ;) (Just like [Capistrano](http://www.capistranorb.com/))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the dev environment as much the same as production one, best option for you is [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/).

However it can be done in VirtualBox only (without Vagrant).

Comment: That isn't true, Vagrant supports all sorts of providers, including VMWare.

Comment: @Brad I know. I meant that initial question can be solved in VB only (without Vagrant).

Comment: Oh, I understand what you are saying now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's entirely possible to achieve what you want... in fact, it's a pretty standard way of doing things.

What you need to is map a directory on your VM to your host machine.  You can do this with the settings of Virtual Box.

As far as checking and deploying, don't deploy your dev box.  That will have all of your extra logging and what not enabled.  You only need to deploy your code.

I use Vagrant for handling my dev VMs.  It automates the process of mapping drives and provisioning.

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html